# Regex pattern for a number within a number

Tags: regex

Can anyone think of a better way to write this? It works but it is a little ugly.

Input data looks like this: 125100001

The first two numbers are the year, next two are the week number, and last 5 are the serial. I want to validate that the week number is not over 52 for an [angular input[number] pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) option. Basically just to leverage the $error field :)

So here it is:

```
^\d\d(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-2]){1}\d{5}$
```

Comment: What is the programming language

Comment: Implemented in Angular.js as described in my link to the input[number] pattern option.

Comment: this is not a good idea to do this entirely in regex

Comment: @SargeBorsch I check the value in the controller as well but thought I could deliver better message to the user if the week value is illegal. Is that still not recommended?

Comment: @cory.todd did you want to allow `00`? What's the problem with your regex?

Comment: `^\d\d(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])\d{5}$` ?  But I agree that regex is probably not the best way to do it.  I don't know anything about Angular, but is there no way to split the elements of the string into array using a format?  Something like [`scanf()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string) as implemented in so many languages?

Comment: Also, if January 1st is the first day of week 1, then the 365th (and optionally 366th if it's a leap year) day will fall in week 53.  Just sayin'...

Comment: @AvinashRaj, there is no technical issue. Just seeing if there was a cleaner pattern.

Comment: @ghoti yes, I agree that this should not be standalone solution to validation. The validation returns boolean but if the format is invalid, I'd like to catch the format violation(before attempting to parse) and give the user a helpful reason as to why the value is illegal.

Comment: Sure, but if Angular provides something like scanf that will let you break apart the string more easily than a regex, you can still do that.  "Month is invalid" whether you're testing `\\2` from `^(..)(..)(.....)$` or the second field of `%2d%2d%5d`.  And a regex *validation* will only fail, not provide you with a reason or position of failure.

Comment: Point taken, I'll go about it another route. I can just write a different controller function to do as you suggest and then return a detailed description of what's wrong (if anything). Thanks for your input, ghoti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the week part:

```
[0-4]\d|5[0-2]
```

so the entire regex would be:

```
^\d\d([0-4]\d|5[0-2])\d{5}$
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! This directly answers my question although there was some good discussion regarding my original logic from ghoti.

Comment: It may not be a problem for the OP, but this will allow `00` for a week number.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
^(\d{2})([0-4][1-9]|[1-5]0|5[12])(\d{5})$
```

Notes

- The first set of parentheses `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` validates the month: 01-12
- The second set of parentheses `([0-4][1-9]|[1-5]0|5[12])` validates the week: 01-52
- If you wish, you can retrieve each component with groups 1, 2 and 2

Comment: The second set of parentheses is clever. The first part though, I do **not** have a limitation on the year. Any value, 00-99 is valid.

Comment: I missed that. For some reason I thought the two first digits were a month. Just changed it to `\d{2}` (similar to the serial)